# How to upload a file using Dajax

Tags: django, file-upload, dajaxice

I am trying to upload a file using a form with Dajax.

I use `serializeObject` to serialize data with JavaScript. However, an input with a file type is not serialized before it sends to the server. Is there any way to upload a file using Dajax?